# Not able to read json test data file into my stepDef

Tags: java, json, selenium, qaf, perfecto

Not able to read json test data file into my stepDef. When I try to execute this in maven I am getting below error message.

My Scenario
Scenario Outline: JSON Keyword Example
Given I am on github login page
#And I enter "" and ""
And I enter usernames and passwords

```
Examples: {'datafile':'./src/main/resources/data/testData.json'}
```

My testData.json

```
[
  { "username" : "jsonuser1" , "password":"jsonpass1" , "isvalid":"false" }
]
```

StepDefinition

```
@And("^I enter usernames and passwords$")
public void iEnterUsernamesAndPasswords(Map<Object, Object> data) {
    System.out.println("*************************"+ data.get("username") + data.get("password"));
    
}
```

Error Msg:

```
init done 
08:48:10:169: Executing get parameters: {"url":"https://github.com/login"} 
08:48:10:778: command: get[ param-1: {url=https://github.com/login}] Result: null 
[WINDOWS  90.0.4430.212]: ▀ ▀ ▀ END STEP: Given I am on github login page ▀ ▀ ▀
08:48:10:781: Completed Teststep: Given I am on github login page 
08:48:10:787: Invoking Teststep: And I enter usernames and passwords 
[WINDOWS  90.0.4430.212]: ▄ ▄ ▄ BEGIN STEP: And I enter usernames and passwords ▄ ▄ ▄
08:48:10:787: Failure Teststep: And I enter usernames and passwords 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Wrong number of parameters, Expected 1 parameters but Actual is 0
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.JavaStep.processArgs(JavaStep.java:206) ~[qaf-2.1.15.jar:?]
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.JavaStep.doExecute(JavaStep.java:149) ~[qaf-2.1.15.jar:?]
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.BaseTestStep.execute(BaseTestStep.java:146) [qaf-2.1.15.jar:?]
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.StringTestStep.execute(StringTestStep.java:126) [qaf-2.1.15.jar:?]
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario.execute(Scenario.java:174) [qaf-2.1.15.jar:?]
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario.scenario(DataDrivenScenario.java:66) [qaf-2.1.15.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:778) [qaf-2.1.15.jar:?]
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632) [qaf-2.1.15.jar:?]
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:39) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:421) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
[WINDOWS  90.0.4430.212]: ▀ ▀ ▀ END STEP: And I enter usernames and passwords ▀ ▀ ▀
08:48:10:787: Completed Teststep: And I enter usernames and passwords 
08:48:10:787: Competed scenario: JSON Keyword Example with status FAILURE 
08:48:10:806: Executing screenshot parameters: {} 
08:48:11:023: Executing quit parameters: {} 
08:48:11:025: command: quit[ param-1: {}] Result: Cannot invoke "String.toLowerCase()" because the return value of "com.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.PropertyUtil.getString(String)" is null 
08:48:11:026: Cannot invoke "String.toLowerCase()" because the return value of "com.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.PropertyUtil.getString(String)" is null 
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.093 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
JSON Keyword Example(com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario)  Time elapsed: 2.984 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Wrong number of parameters, Expected 1 parameters but Actual is 0
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario.scenario(DataDrivenScenario.java:66)
08:48:11:225: Stopping chrome driver service. 
Results :
Failed tests: 
  DataDrivenScenario.scenario:66->Scenario.execute:174 » Runtime Wrong number of...
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For any step that required arguments, you need to specify argument placeholder when defining step and need to provide value the time of call.
In your case try to update step definition as below:

```
@And("^I enter usernames and passwords \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void iEnterUsernamesAndPasswords(Map<Object, Object> data) {
System.out.println("*************************"+ data.get("username") + data.get("password"));
}
```

Pass the data at the time of step call,

```
My Scenario
  Scenario Outline: JSON Keyword Example
    Given I am on github login page
    And I enter usernames and passwords "${args[0]}"

    Examples: {'datafile':'./src/main/resources/data/testData.json'}
```